# Primefaces : How to create clickable sections in Primefaces?

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I want 4 "quarters" (sections) in a page and all 4 of them should be clickable and must have onclick event. The entire section should be clickable, not just any small button on it. How shall I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a panelGrid with 2 columns and 2 rows. In each box insert a commandButton styled to be very large.